# jquery simple hide show based on checkbox checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to show and hide the options inside the main based on checkbox checked or not. I have many checkbox but here I am checking address checkbox.

This is my checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" id="address">Mark it
```

here is div I want to hide/show

```
<div id="options">
//div
</div>

 if($('#address').prop('checked')){
        $('#options').show()
      }else{
        $('#options').hide()
      }
```

Above code is not working for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your code not working, you only check the condition checkbox check or not you have to call the **checkbox change event** also every time when the checkbox gets clicked.
here is a working demo hope it will help you to understand how jquery works.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#options').hide();
    $('#address').change(function () {
        if ($('#address').prop('checked')) {
            $('#options').show()
        } else {
            $('#options').hide()
        }
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="options">
//div
</div>
<input type="checkbox" id="address">Mark it
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code will only work on the `first time` not every time the value of the checkbox changes.

You have to add `event listener` on change of the `checked` value of checkbox

```
$("#address").on("change", e => {
  const isChecked = e.target.checked;
  if (isChecked) $('#options').show()
  else $('#options').hide()
})
```

```js
if ($('#address').prop('checked')) {
  $('#options').show()
} else {
  $('#options').hide()
}

$("#address").on("change", e => {
  const isChecked = e.target.checked;
  if (isChecked) $('#options').show()
  else $('#options').hide()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="address">Mark it
<div id="options">
  //div
</div>
```